# Rhino mocks generics issue

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have an interface that I need to mock -

```
 public interface IRepositoryCachable  
 {
     IEnumerable<T> All<T>() where T : ICacheEntity;
     void Delete<T>(T item) where T : ICacheEntity;
     void Add<T>(T item) where T : ICacheEntity;
     void Update();
     T SingleOrDefault<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : ICacheEntity;
     IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : ICacheEntity;
 }
```

Here is my test -

```
var repo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepositoryCachable>();
repo.Expect(x => x.Add(Arg<ICacheEntity>.Is.Anything));

testClass = new testclass(repo);

testClass.Add;

repo.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

`testClass.Add` calls `repo.Add`. But in `VerifyAllExpectation();` it barfs stating that Add was not called.

Code for test class - pseudo -

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void Add()
    {
         _repo.Add( new CacheEntity());
    }
}
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here I think is that you are setting up an expectation for the method Add to be called but this method is distinct from Add which is the method you are really calling.

In short either change you expectation to:

`repo.Expect(x => x.Add(Arg<CacheEntity>.Is.Anything));`

Or change your non-test code to:
`_repo.Add<ICacheEntity>(new CacheEntity());`

I am assuming you will not want to do the second since you put a generic parameter on that method and the only reason to do that is because you need to have the parameter be typed to the concrete type.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you testing implementation details (what was called?) instead of behavior (that it was added to a database, or that a cached entity was returned, or whatever)?

Comment: You cannot have a database in your unit-tests. So that's the usual course of action - you mock a repository, and go with London-school unit-testing approach, i.e. behaviour testing, i.e. "what was called". (You seem to use the term "behaviour", where you mean state-based testing (Chicago school), which is another level of confusion).

Answer (score 0):

This line seems suspect:

```
testClass.Add;
```

Should a parameter be passed to this method?  I don't even see how this can compile to be honest.

Comment: Well, OP has not included any details about `testClass`. For all you know, `Add` could be a property.

Comment: Sorry it is testClass.Add(); I have editted my question. Issue still remains!

Comment: Is this some syntax I'm not aware of?  You can just say "testClass.Add;" with no assignment and no parens?  That won't compile, property or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GenerateStub` instead of `GenerateMock`.  Stubs are usually used for interfaces.  I usually only use mocks when I'm mocking out actual class members.

Comment: You should not use stubs in Rhinomocks in conjunction with VerifyAllExpections.  See: http://lostechies.com/sharoncichelli/2010/03/19/rhino-mocks-examples-with-a-fix/

Comment: Ah, yes, you're correct.  I forgot about the expectations.  So I would use a stub, but don't use the Expect and instead use AssertWasCalled after running your test.

Comment: That's usually the approach I take as well.  I don't like VerifyAll.  :/